# Retrieving info on a youtube video for iOS

Tags: ios, video, download, youtube

Two questions:

http://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id=jN0nWjvzeNc

to get the 'token' parameter value, how is that parsed, i.e. is the response a JSON object?

Second, is this something I need to call for each video id such that the token id is different for each video, or can I call it once and store the token in any given session and use it for every video I download?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the token value is different for each different youtube video.

And for token parsing I use simple query parser which I have written myself in C++ which simply parse tokens separated by '&'.

Usually the get_video_info file format is as below:

status=ok&..........&token=val&thumbnail_url=val....

Btw I use linux, but I think the logic will be same for ios too...